# How have I to change the .htaccess file content to avoid the rewrite role that place "www." before the server name?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have some problem with a PHP website running on XAMPP. I think that the problem should be caused by the **.htaccess** file that rewrite my URL.

Basically I have the following situation:

Into my **C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf** file I have declared this virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/MyProject-Panda"
    ServerName panda.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Then into the **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts** file I have defined that:

```
127.0.0.1       panda.dev
```

The problem is that when in the browser I try to open the **pand.dev** domain (my virtual host) it is automatically rewrited into **http://www.panda.dev/** and it says that can't contact the server.

I think that the problem should be in some **rewrite role** of the website **.htaccess** file but I am not so into this topic. This is my **.htaccess** content:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/plain text/xml application/x-javascript application/x-httpd-php
    </ifModule>
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip
    </ifModule>
</ifModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 7200 seconds"
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|icon|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 2592000 seconds"
    </FilesMatch>
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 7200 seconds"
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 7200 seconds"
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge"
    <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|gif|png|jpe?g|pdf|xml|oga|ogg|m4a|ogv|mp3|mp4|m4v|webm|svg|svgz|eot|ttf|otf|woff|ico|webp|appcache|manifest|htc|crx|xpi|safariextz|vcf)$" >
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>
    Header append Vary User-Agent
    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff|font.css)$">
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf|css|gz)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(js)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, private"
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.(html|htm)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=7200, public"
    </FilesMatch>
    # Disable caching for scripts and other dynamic files
    <FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
        Header unset Cache-Control
    </FilesMatch>
    Header unset ETag
</IfModule>

FileETag none
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.*
    RewriteRule .* – [F,L]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\"|%22).*(<|>|%3) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (javascript:).*(\;) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C).*script.*(>|%3) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\;|\'|\"|%22).*(union|select|insert|drop|update|md5|benchmark|or|and|if) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (base64_encode|localhost|mosconfig) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (boot\.ini|echo.*kae|etc/passwd) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (GLOBALS|REQUEST)(=|\[|%) [NC]
    RewriteRule .* - [E=BadQueryString,F]

    RewriteRule ^ - [E=BASE:/PandaOk/] [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}:s on:(s) 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /admin/
    RewriteRule .* - [S=2]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ %{ENV:BASE}$1 [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9!-/]*)$ %{ENV:BASE} [L]
</IfModule>
```

What have I to change to avoid this rewrite behavior?

Answer (score 0):

remove (or comment) these lines:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}:s on:(s) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```